# Tooltip CSS: Remove new line

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip_transition

But I want to get the "Hover Over Me" text right next to the "When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible."

For example, the ideal output would be:

> When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will
> fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible.
> **Hover over me**

instead of

> When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will
> fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible.
>
> **Hover over me**

The tool tip should obviously still show up on hover. What part of the CSS would I have to change?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -60px;
    
    /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<h2>Fade In Tooltip on Hover</h2>
<p>When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible.</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about changing the structure a little put the `Hover over me` text in a `<span>` and not a `<div>` and then put that inside the `<p>` tag like this:

```
<body style="text-align:center;">
<h2>Fade In Tooltip on Hover</h2>
<p>When you move the mouse over the text below, the tooltip text will fade in and take 1 second to go from completely invisible to visible. <span class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</span></p>
</body>
```

Here is a **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/753s67ot/)** showing it

Let me explain a little as well: in HTML a `<p>` tag is a `block` element and, thus, it cannot allow other `block` elements inside of it (such as `<div>`). The `<span>` tag is not `block`, it is `inline`, allowing you to place it in side of a `<p>` tag. Often times, we use `<span>` tags when we want to edit text inside of a `<p>` tag because it doesn't break the text in the `<span>` tag into a new line like a `<div>` or a second `<p>` tag would do (as you saw in your example.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is on two lines is that the paragraph tag enclosing the instructions is a block level element. Meaning it will start and end a new line. You could set the display of this element in your css as inline and it should show text as inline.

```
p{
    display: inline;
}
```